# PIVOT error in this sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this table

```
CUSTOMERNAME |  PRODUCTNAME  |  AMMOUNT
=======================================
Customer1       Product1         10
Customer1       Product1         100
Customer2       Product2         20
Customer2       Product2         200
Customer1       Product2         30
Customer1       Product2        300
Customer2       Product1         40
Customer2       Product1        400
```

I need to have this table:

```
Product1      |  Product2       .|.. ProductN
=================================
Sum(ammount)       Sum(Ammount)  |   Sum(Ammount)
```

#### What I have tried

I understood that I need to use PIVOT.

This is my try

```
Selectt temp.Product1, temp.Product2
FROM
(
select ProductName, Ammount
from CustomerProducts
)
PIVOT(
  SUM(Ammount)
  FOR ProductName IN (['Product1'])
) as temp
```

This is the exception I got

```
Incorrect syntax near '.'.: Selectt temp.Product1, temp.Product2 FROM ( select ProductName, Ammount from CustomerProducts ) PIVOT( SUM(Ammount) FOR ProductName IN (['Product1']) ) as temp
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d401b/25)

Comment: Remove the single quotes, and include all products you wish to pivot, should just be `FOR ProductName IN ([Product1], [Product2])`, you also need to give your subquery an alias. [Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d401b/28)

Comment: @GarethD what I did what you said, I got this exception `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "queries_pkey" Detail: Key (id, schema_def_id)=(26, 974197) already exists.`

Comment: @GarethD I showed you the error from the sql fiddle, you can try it yourself there. I am not working on any database server

Comment: I have posted a link to a working SQL Fiddle in my original comment

Comment: @GarethD I just saw it. please check my Fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d401b/26 the same as yours but the exception exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes, and include all products you wish to pivot, should just be FOR ProductName IN ([Product1], [Product2]), you also need to give your subquery an alias. You have also put two ts in `selectt`.

Making the final query:

```
SELECT  temp.Product1, temp.Product2
FROM    (   SELECT  ProductName, Ammount
            FROM    CustomerProducts
        ) AS c -- SUBQUERY ALIAS HERE
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(Ammount)
            FOR ProductName IN ([Product1], [Product2]) -- REMOVE SINGLE QUOTES, INCLUDE ALL PRODUCTS
        ) AS temp;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d401b/31)**